# How to read a pixel from a Depth Texture efficiently?

Tags: opengl

I have an OpenGL Texture and want to be able to read back a single pixel's value, so I can display it on the screen. If the texture is a regular old RGB texture or the like, this is no problem: I take an empty Framebuffer Object that I have lying around, attach the texture to COLOR0 on the framebuffer and call:

```
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &c);
```

Where c is essentially a float[4].

However, when it is a depth texture, I have to go down a different code path, setting the DEPTH attachment instead of the COLOR0, and calling:

```
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &c);
```

where c is a float. This works fine on my Windows 7 computer running NVIDIA GeForce 580, but causes an error on my old 2008 MacBook pro. Specifically, after attaching the depth texture to the framebuffer, if I call glCheckFrameBufferStatus(GL_READ_BUFFER), I get GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER.

After searching the OpenGL documentation, I found this line, which seems to imply that OpenGL does *not* support reading from a depth component of a framebuffer if there is no color attachment:

```
GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER is returned if GL_READ_BUFFER is not GL_NONE 
and the value of GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE is GL_NONE for the color 
attachment point named by GL_READ_BUFFER.
```

Sure enough, if I create a temporary color texture and bind it to COLOR0, no errors occur when I readPixels from the depth texture.

Now creating a temporary texture every time (EDIT: or even once and having GPU memory tied up by it) through this code is annoying and potentially slow, so I was wondering if anyone knew of an alternative way to read a single pixel from a depth texture? (Of course if there is no better way I will keep around one texture to resize when needed and use only that for the temporary color attachment, but this seems rather roundabout).

Comment: "Now creating a temporary texture every time through this code " Why would you create a temporary texture *every time through this code*? Why wouldn't you just create it one time and leave it attached to the FBO?

Comment: I *do* go on to say "I will keep around one texture to resize when needed and use only that for the temporary color attachment." I only did it that way to test if that'd work. But the way I phrased it was confusing, so I will change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is contained in your error message:

> if GL_READ_BUFFER is not GL_NONE

So do that; set the read buffer to `GL_NONE`. With [`glReadBuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glReadBuffer). Like this:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); //where fbo is your FBO.
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

That way, the FBO is properly complete, even though it only has a depth texture.

Comment: Great, it works perfectly. I knew I was missing something but I was half-resigned to the answer just being that the OpenGL spec is silly.